# Comparing a list with a dictionary and producing new list. Length of new list is 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to produce a List B by comparing elements from List A with X elements in Dictionary. The List B should produce all Y elements from the dictionary where X and List A match.

Here is my list and the dictionary (this is a DNA translation to protein program):

```
tuple = 'gagcatgttggcctggtcctttgctaggtactgtagagcaggtgagagagtgagggggaaggactccaaattagaccagttcttagccatgaagcagagactctgaagccagactacctgggtcccaatcttgggcttggtatttcctcgctgtgtgactctggactgcgccatggggctcagcgacggggaatggcagttggtgctgaacgtctgggggaaggtggaggctgacatcccaggccatgggcaggaagtcctcatcaggctctttaagggtcacccagagactctggagaagtttgacaagttcaagcacctgaagtcagaggacgagatgaaggcgtctgaggacttaaagaagcatggtgccaccgtgctcaccgccctgggtggcatccttaagaagaaggggcatcatgaggcagagattaagcccctggcacagtcgcatgccaccaagcacaagatccccgtgaagtacctggagttcatctcggaatgcatcatccaggttctgcagagcaagcatcccggggactttggtgctgatgcccagggggccatgaacaaggccctggagctgttccggaaggacatggcctccaactacaaggagctgggcttccagggctaggcccctgccgctcccacccccacccatctgggccccgggttcaagagagagcggggtctgatctcgtgtagccatatagagtttgcttctgagtgtctgctttgtttagtagaggtgggcaggaggagctgaggggctggggctggggtgttgaagttggctttgcatgcccagcgatgcgcctccctgtgggatgtcatcaccctgggaaccgggagtggcccttggctcactgtgttctgcatggtttggatctgaattaattgtcctttcttctaaatcccaaccgaacttcttccaacctccaaactggctgtaaccccaaatccaagccattaactacacctgacagtagcaattgtctgattaatcactggccccttgaagacagcagaatgtccctttgcaatgaggaggagatctgggctgggcgggccagctggggaagcatttgactatctggaacttgtgtgtgcctcctcaggtatggcagtgactcacctggttttaataaaacaacctgcaacatctca'

diction = {'aaa': 'LYS', 'aac': 'ASN', 'aag': 'LYS', 'aat': 'ASN', 'aca': 'THR', 'acc': 'THR', 'acg': 'THR', 'act': 'THR', 'aga': 'ARG', 'agc': 'SER', 'agg': 'ARG', 'agt': 'SER', 'ata': 'ILE', 'atc': 'ILE', 'atg': 'MET', 'att': 'ILE', 'caa': 'GLN', 'cac': 'HIS', 'cag': 'GLN', 'cat': 'HIS', 'cca': 'PRO', 'ccc': 'PRO', 'ccg': 'PRO', 'cct': 'PRO', 'cga': 'ARG', 'cgc': 'ARG', 'cgg': 'ARG', 'cgt': 'ARG', 'cta': 'LEU', 'ctc': 'LEU', 'ctg': 'LEU', 'ctt': 'LEU', 'gaa': 'GLU', 'gac': 'ASP', 'gag': 'GLU', 'gat': 'ASP', 'gca': 'ALA', 'gcc': 'ALA', 'gcg': 'ALA', 'gct': 'ALA', 'gga': 'GLY', 'ggc': 'GLY', 'ggg': 'GLY', 'ggt': 'GLY', 'gta': 'VAL', 'gtc': 'VAL', 'gtg': 'VAL', 'gtt': 'VAL', 'taa': '***', 'tac': 'TYR', 'tag': '***', 'tat': 'TYR', 'tca': 'SER', 'tcc': 'SER', 'tcg': 'SER', 'tct': 'SER', 'tga': '***', 'tgc': 'CYS', 'tgg': 'TRP', 'tgt': 'CYS', 'tta': 'LEU', 'ttc': 'PHE', 'ttg': 'LEU', 'ttt': 'PHE'}
```

This is my code:

```
protlist = []
for i in range(0,Len): # Len is length of tuple
    tu = tuple[3*i:3*i+3]

    if tu in diction:
        for x,y in diction.items():
            if tu == x:
                protlist = [y]
                print(*protlist,end =" ") # This prints each y value in a linear fashion
                break
print(len(protlist))
```

This is my expected output:

```
GLU HIS VAL GLY LEU VAL LEU CYS *** VAL LEU *** SER ARG *** GLU SER GLU GLY GLU GLY LEU GLN ILE ARG PRO VAL LEU SER HIS GLU ALA GLU THR LEU LYS PRO ASP TYR LEU GLY PRO ASN LEU GLY LEU GLY ILE SER SER LEU CYS ASP SER GLY LEU ARG HIS GLY ALA GLN ARG ARG GLY MET ALA VAL GLY ALA GLU ARG LEU GLY GLU GLY GLY GLY *** HIS PRO ARG PRO TRP ALA GLY SER PRO HIS GLN ALA LEU *** GLY SER PRO ARG ASP SER GLY GLU VAL *** GLN VAL GLN ALA PRO GLU VAL ARG GLY ARG ASP GLU GLY VAL *** GLY LEU LYS GLU ALA TRP CYS HIS ARG ALA HIS ARG PRO GLY TRP HIS PRO *** GLU GLU GLY ALA SER *** GLY ARG ASP *** ALA PRO GLY THR VAL ALA CYS HIS GLN ALA GLN ASP PRO ARG GLU VAL PRO GLY VAL HIS LEU GLY MET HIS HIS PRO GLY SER ALA GLU GLN ALA SER ARG GLY LEU TRP CYS *** CYS PRO GLY GLY HIS GLU GLN GLY PRO GLY ALA VAL PRO GLU GLY HIS GLY LEU GLN LEU GLN GLY ALA GLY LEU PRO GLY LEU GLY PRO CYS ARG SER HIS PRO HIS PRO SER GLY PRO ARG VAL GLN GLU ARG ALA GLY SER ASP LEU VAL *** PRO TYR ARG VAL CYS PHE *** VAL SER ALA LEU PHE SER ARG GLY GLY GLN GLU GLU LEU ARG GLY TRP GLY TRP GLY VAL GLU VAL GLY PHE ALA CYS PRO ALA MET ARG LEU PRO VAL GLY CYS HIS HIS PRO GLY ASN ARG GLU TRP PRO LEU ALA HIS CYS VAL LEU HIS GLY LEU ASP LEU ASN *** LEU SER PHE LEU LEU ASN PRO ASN ARG THR SER SER ASN LEU GLN THR GLY CYS ASN PRO LYS SER LYS PRO LEU THR THR PRO ASP SER SER ASN CYS LEU ILE ASN HIS TRP PRO LEU GLU ASP SER ARG MET SER LEU CYS ASN GLU GLU GLU ILE TRP ALA GLY ARG ALA SER TRP GLY SER ILE *** LEU SER GLY THR CYS VAL CYS LEU LEU ARG TYR GLY SER ASP SER PRO GLY PHE ASN LYS THR THR CYS ASN ILE SER 390
```

This code will superficially produce the correct list. However when I call for the length of the list, it is outputted as 1.
I tried replacing protlist = [y] with protlist.append(y). This gave the correct length of the list and the wrong output.

I also tried using the join function instead with ''.join(y) but this also gave the incorrect length of the list.

How can I edit the code so that both the correct output and length of list is achieved? Thank you.

Comment: is X the value of dictionary or key of dictionary ?

Comment: Sorry should have made that clearer; x is the key, y is the value

Comment: Can we please see an example of your `list`s and `dict`, as well as your expected output?

Comment: Hi - just added these to my question now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `len(protlist) = 1` because you reassign a single value as `protlist` for every single loop in `for x,y in diction.items()`. 
Then, replacing `protlist = [y]` with `protlist.append(y)` gives you the wrong output, because you print `protlist` in every single loop.

To start however, `Len` should not be the length of `tuple`. The length of tuple is `1170`, but in every loop `tu` has three characters, and then you move on to the next three. So you need `1170 / 3 = 390` iterations to get to the end of your string.

Then there are a number of ways to solve your problem. An example with a list and join like you mentioned is appending value in the loop, then doing the printing and counting outside of the loop.

```
protlist = []

for i in range(0, int(len(tuple) / 3)):
    tu = tuple[3*i:3*i+3]
    if tu in diction:
        for x, y in diction.items():
            if tu == x:
                protlist.append(y)
                break

print(' '.join(protlist)) #prints list items separated by a space
print(len(protlist))
```

I tested this against your expected output, and it gives me that exact result.

**Edit:** 
example of list comprehension for a similar, simplified version of this question:

```
string = 'aaabbbcccdddeee'
dictionary = {'aaa': 'A', 'bbb': 'B', 'ccc': 'C', 'ddd': 'D', 'eee': 'E'}

parts = [ string[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(string), 3) ]
output = [ dictionary[x] for x in parts if x in dictionary.keys() ]
print(' '.join(output))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! that was super helpful; appreciate it :)

Comment: You're very welcome. If you're not familiar with list comprehension, you might find that interesting to look into, it could help condense your code and make some parts easier to follow. I'll edit my answer and add an example.